# Postgres notify if connection timeout is occured

Tags: postgresql

I want to set up a separate connection for every user of my app.
I have some data structure for this to store connections.
Obviously, I should delete the expired connections somehow.
There are multiple ways to do it.

The best one is to make a callback between Postgres and my app when a connection timeout has occurred. So my app will have some function like `on_connection_timeout` to remove old connections.

But is Postgres have at all such feature to tell about connection timeout?

P.S. If no - I will implenet a FIFO

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL v14 introduced the parameter [`idle_session_timeout`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-IDLE-SESSION-TIMEOUT), which is exactly what you are looking for.  Note that the client will get an error if it tries to use a connection that has been closed by the server.